# Backbone.js collection url schema

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

My new application main collection is still very basic:

```
var TransactionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Transaction,
    url: '/api/transactions'
});
```

This is good while developing, but now I'd like to add some pagination and filtering features.

I'm not sure about what URL schema I should use. I mean:

- page 1, all transactions, January 2014 => /api/transactions/2014/01
- page 2, all transactions, January 2014 => /api/transactions/2014/01?p=2
- page 1, all transactions, February 2014 => /api/transactions/2014/02
- page 1, only incomes, June 2014 => /api/transactions/incomes/2014/06
- page 2, only outcomes, June 2014 => /api/transactions/outcomes/2014/06/?p=2

Is it a good structure, in your opinion?

In each case, what's the best practice for managing such a collection? I guess I can make the *url:* property a function, to dynamically handle several parameters (page, filter, period) passed to the collection before fetching it.
Or is it better to pass parameters with each fetch?

Comment: http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/

Comment: ok so I should use GET query parameters for all above cases, right?

Comment: yes, I added examples below in my answer for each your url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [best practices](http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/)

- page 1, all transactions, January 2014 => /api/transactions?year=2014&month=01
- page 2, all transactions, January 2014 => /api/transactions?year=2014&month=01&offset=20&limit=20
- page 1, all transactions, February 2014 => /api/transactions?year=2014&month=02
- page 1, only incomes, June 2014 => /api/transactions?year=2014&month=06&filter=incomes
- page 2, only outcomes, June 2014 => /api/transactions?year=2014&month=06&filter=outcomes&offset=20&limit=20

To send the query string use `data` attribute in ajax options like this

```
transactionCollection.fetch({
    data: {
        limit: 20,
        offset: 20,
        year: "2014",
        month: "01"
    }
});
```

Comment: So URL path should only be used for "resources", and not for search parameters such as dates, pagination, and so on?